# error: type '(dynamic) => CountModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

i am trying to get data from API but getting error like this
error: type '(dynamic) => CountModel' is not a subtype of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>' of 'transform'

this is my code to get data

```
List<dynamic> angka = [];
getCount() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    try {
      Uri url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/count');
      final http.Response response = await http.get(url, headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
      });
      // response.request;
      DMethod.printResponse(response);
      angka = jsonDecode(response.body)['count']
          .map((e) => CountModel.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
      setState(() {});
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
```

And this is my CountModel

```
CountModel countModelFromJson(String str) => CountModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String countModelToJson(CountModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class CountModel {
    final int nama;
    final int agama;
    final int tgl;
    final int cuti;
    final int overtime;
    final int medical;
    final int travel;
    final int destination;
    final int acomodation;

    CountModel({
        required this.nama,
        required this.agama,
        required this.tgl,
        required this.cuti,
        required this.overtime,
        required this.medical,
        required this.travel,
        required this.destination,
        required this.acomodation,
    });

    factory CountModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CountModel(
        nama: json["nama"],
        agama: json["agama"],
        tgl: json["tgl"],
        cuti: json["cuti"],
        overtime: json["overtime"],
        medical: json["medical"],
        travel: json["travel"],
        destination: json["destination"],
        acomodation: json["acomodation"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "nama": nama,
        "agama": agama,
        "tgl": tgl,
        "cuti": cuti,
        "overtime": overtime,
        "medical": medical,
        "travel": travel,
        "destination": destination,
        "acomodation": acomodation,
    };
}
```

And here is the data i'm trying to get

```
{
    "count": {
        "nama": 2,
        "agama": 2,
        "tgl": 2,
        "cuti": 1,
        "overtime": 1,
        "medical": 0,
        "travel": 3,
        "destination": 1,
        "acomodation": 1
    }
}
```

Previously I also tried to change the data type in CountModel from integer to string, but still error

Comment: you api response are not a `List`. but you handle it as a `List`. try to acces convert directly : `angka = CountModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)['count']))`